# Splitting big.Int by digit

Tags: go

I'm trying to split a `big.Int` into a number of `int64`s such that each is a portion of the larger number, with a standard offset of 18 digits. For example, given the following input value of `1234512351234088800000999`, I would expect the following output: `[351234088800000999, 1234512]`. For negative numbers, I would expect all of the parts to be negative (i.e. `-1234512351234088800000999` produces `[-351234088800000999, -1234512]`).

I already know I can do this to get the result I want:

```
func Split(input *big.Int) []int64 {
    const width = 18

    asStr := in.Coefficient().Text(10)
    strLen := len(asStr)
    offset := 0
    if in.IsNegative() {
        offset = 1
    }

    length := int(math.Ceil(float64(strLen-offset) / width))
    ints := make([]int64, length)
    for i := 1; i <= length; i++ {
        start := strLen - (i * width)
        end := start + width
        if start < 0 || (start == 1 && asStr[0] == '-') {
            start = 0
        }

        ints[i-1], _ = strconv.ParseInt(asStr[start:end], 10, 64)
        if offset == 1 && ints[i-1] > 0 {
            ints[i-1] = 0 - ints[i-1]
        }
    }

    return ints
}
```

However, I don't like the idea of using string-parsing nor do I like the use of `strconv`. Is there a way I can do this utilizing the `big.Int` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DivMod` function to do what you need here, with some special care to handle negative numbers:

```golang
var offset = big.NewInt(1e18)

func Split(input *big.Int) []int64 {
    rest := new(big.Int)
    rest.Abs(input)

    var ints []int64
    r := new(big.Int)
    for {
        rest.DivMod(rest, offset, r)
        ints = append(ints, r.Int64() * int64(input.Sign()))
        if rest.BitLen() == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
    return ints
}
```

Multiplying each output by `input.Sign()` ensures that each output will be negative if the input is negative. The sum of the output values multiplied by 1e18 times their position in the output should equal the input.

Comment: I've edited my question to include conditions for negative numbers as well.